# ¿Por qué no se termina de recibir un archivo en socket TCP en Python?

Tags: python, socket, tcp

Tengo los siguientes sockets TCP en Python

**Servidor**

```
import socket
import os
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
BUFFER_SIZE=2048
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('192.168.100.35', 10000)
print('starting up on {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.bind(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)
cont=True
# Wait for a connection
print('waiting for a connection')
conn, client_address = sock.accept()
print('connection from', client_address)
# Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
while True:
    if(cont==True):
        comando="Quieres usar algun comando: "
        conn.send(comando.encode('utf-8')) #enviar mensaje
        data1 = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE) #recibir mensaje
        if(data1.decode('utf-8')=="no"): #si no quiere usar comandos
            while True: 
                data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE) #recibir mensaje
                if(data.decode('utf-8')=="exit"): #si el mensaje es exit
                    cont=False
                    print("Conexion terminada") #terminar conexion
                    sock.close() #cerrar socket
                if not data: #si no hay datos
                    break #terminar conexion
                if(data.decode('utf-8')!="exit"): #si el mensaje no es exit
                    print("El cliente dice:",data.decode('utf-8')) #imprimir mensaje
                conn.send(data) #enviar mensaje
        if(data1.decode('utf-8')=="si"): #si quiere usar comandos
                archivo=conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE) #recibir mensaje
                print("Quieres descargar el archivo: ",archivo.decode('utf-8')) #imprimir mensaje
                archivo=archivo.decode('utf-8') #convertir a string
                f = open(archivo, "rb") #abrir archivo
                tamano=os.path.getsize(archivo) #obtener tamaño del archivo}[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
                if(f):
                    print("El archivo ",archivo," existe, vamos a enviarlo")
                    l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
                    while (l):
                        conn.sendall(l)
                        l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
                    print("Archivo enviado con exito de ",tamano," bytes")
                    f.close()
    else:
        break
```

**Cliente**

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
BUFFER_SIZE=2048
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
server_address = ('192.168.100.35', 10000)
print('connecting to {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.connect(server_address)

data = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
print(data.decode('utf-8'))
comando=input()
sock.send(comando.encode('utf-8'))
if(comando=="no"):
    while(data.decode('utf-8')!="exit"):
        print("Ingresa el mensaje a enviar: ")
        MSG=input()
        sock.send(MSG.encode('utf-8'))
        data = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
if(comando=="si"):
        print("Quieres descargar algo, ingresa el nombre")
        archivo=input()
        sock.send(archivo.encode('utf-8'))
        archivo2="Copia-"+archivo
        f = open(archivo2, "wb")
        l = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        while (l):
            f.write(l)
            #print("Recibiendo archivo... con caracteres como: ",l.hex())
            l = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        print("Archivo recibido con exito")
        f.close()
```

Al momento de tratar de descargar el archivo, el servidor dice que lo manda correctamente, pero el cliente no termina de recibir el archivo, se queda de la siguiente manera:

[image: resultado]

Como se puede ver, el cliente se queda ciclado y el servidor ya acabó de mandar el archivo.
¿Qué error hay? Lo que hace el cliente es que mientras "l" tenga datos, que los escriba en el archivo, pero al momento de recibir los últimos datos se queda ciclado y no termina ese ciclo while, ¿Qué se puede hacer para que este error no ocurra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código tiene varios problemas, pero el error que buscas está aquí:

*cliente.py*

```
    while (l):
        f.write(l)
        l = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

En esta parte estás leyendo el archivo que te mandan, pero también te comes cualquier cosa que el servidor te envíe tras el contenido mismo. Nunca detectas una condición de término; sigues grabando indefinidamente.

*[`sock.recv()` no falla si no hay nada que leer. Lo que hace es quedarse esperando hasta leer `BUFFER_SIZE` caracteres.]*

Mientras tanto, el servidor está ejecutando aqui:

*server.py*

```
while True:
    if(cont==True):
        comando="Quieres usar algun comando: "
        conn.send(comando.encode('utf-8')) #enviar mensaje
```

El resultado es que el mensaje "Quieres usar algun comando: " se lee y se graba en el archivo del cliente.

**Solución**

Tienes que cambiar el protocolo para que el cliente sepa cuando se terminó el archivo.

Una manera sería enviar servidor->cliente la cuenta de los bytes en el archivo.

Cuando el cliente termine de leer dicha cantidad de bytes, lo que viene son comandos/preguntas/dialogo del servidor.